# How do I populate the VALUEs in one column with the FIELD NAMES of another list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, external-content-type, external-list, business-data-catalog

I'm trying to create a 'request update form' where the user selects an entry which is incorrect and then which field is incorrect and writes a comment and that form will get submitted via workflow to the original list manager who will update it.... (i've disabled Update functionality on the main list to be updated for normal users and this can only be done by the manager). How do I get the values in that 'field to update' field in the update form to populate automatically based on the column names in the main form without manually typing them in (there's quite a few).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of updating a field.
But in your case if your using workflows, can't you use your Collect Data from user result, where you will have the field name in one variable the value in another and a comment. Then request approval from the Manager. If he approves use an Update List Item activity to update the item in question, as you already know which item, what field and the value.
Of course you need to put in place a way for the user to only input valid field names or validate their input. But should this not be the process to do so?